# Compilar varias clases y ejecutar en Java

Tags: java

Dispongo de dos clases simples denominadas Person y Main respectivamente tal y como se muestra a continuación. He compilado ambas clases haciendo uso del comando `javac *.java` y este me ha generado los correspondientes archivos `.class` pero cuando intento ejecutar la clase Main de la forma `java Main` este me muestra un error indicando que el símbolo `Person` no existe.

La duda reside en como puedo ejecutar el programa main compilado previamente. La salida esperada  al ejecutar el programa es el nombre resultado de la llamada al método `getName()` incluido en el método `main()`

**Ejemplo:**

```
package test;

public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;    
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("John", 30);
        System.out.println(person.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Corriendo `javac *.java` lanza errores. Seguro que este ejemplo minimo es lo que tienes? La clase Person está en un package `test`, que no importas en `Main`. Si yo dejo todo en el package por defecto (sin package declarado), todo funciona. Si dejo ese `package test` en Person, eso no compila porque Main no importa nada. Entonces, ¿cómo está en tu caso?

Comment: Agrega la línea de comando que ejecuta el programa.

Comment: @Alfabravo Cierto, por un error a la hora de establecer el formato del código aquí, no se mostró que la clase Main también pertenece al paquete `test`

Comment: @Sal Los comandos exactos que ejecuto son los siguientes: `javac *.java` y `java Main`

Comment: Prueba con `java -cp test Main`

Comment: @Sal Me muestra: `error: Class names, 'Main', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes ésta estructura:

```
- unDirectorio
  - Main.java
  - Person.java
```

Haz:

```
cd unDirectorio
javac -d . *.java
java test.Main
```

Observa que con `-d` se crea un directorio con el nombre del paquete;
de tal manera que al incluir dicho nombre de paquete al ejecutar
la Máquina Virtual sabrá dónde ubicar el *código de bytes* de la clase principal.

Otra forma, con una estructura mas recomendable (cada elemento de la ruta del paquete es un directorio):

```
- src
  - test
    - Main.java
    - Person.java
```

A partir del directorio `src`:

```
cd src
javac -d ./test test/*.java
java -cp test test.Main
```