# no reconoce metodo de otra clase al compilar Java

Tags: java, compilar, metodos

tarde o noches.
Estoy haciendo un repaso de POO con java.
Al empezar trabajaba con **VS Code** pero por razones varias me he tenido que pasar a usar **VIM**.
El problema es que, al llamar al metodo **limpiarConsola** perteneciente a la clase **Herramientas** desde la clase **Principal** y tratar de compilar usando **javac** me sale:

Principal.java:11: error: cannot find symbol

```
    Herramientas.limpiarConsola();
    ^
  symbol:   variable Herramientas
  location: class Principal
```

Lo escrito en la clase **Herramientas** es:

```
package logica;

public class Herramientas {

  // Atributos
  private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Metodos

  public static void limpiarConsola() {
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    System.out.flush();
  }
}
```

Y lo perteneciente a la clase **Principal** es:

```
package logica;

public class Principal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    programa();
  }

  public static void programa() {
    Herramientas.limpiarConsola();
    System.out.println("Prueba de la clase: Herramientas.");
  }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu código me funciona perfectamente https://www.online-java.com/g4oFZT5jBt

Comment: No sé cómo estás compilando el código pero debería funcionarte. Asegúrate de que ambas clases están en el mismo directorio

Comment: buenos dias. Ambas clases estan en la misma carpeta. Y para compilar entro al directorio con la terminal y escribo: javac Principal.java y ahi es donde me sale el error.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva ver esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547871/compilar-varias-clases-y-ejecutar-en-java